# How do I put <%=%> tags into asp gridview

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText='<%=scheduledLogsDateCaptionValue%>' 
      DataField="DateString" 
      ItemStyle-Width="15%" 
      ItemStyle-cssclass="logtd" 
      ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
```

Header text shows as `<%=scheduledLogsDateCaptionValue%>` on the site rather than the actual value, anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically change the Header Text of the `GridView` you can do it in the code behind like

```
Gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["scheduledLogsDateCaptionValue"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

isn't that just the *header value*, so you would just add some free text in there and then have `DataField=scheduledLogsDateCaptionValue`?

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Scheduled date" 
      DataField="scheduledLogsDateCaptionValue" 
      ItemStyle-Width="15%" 
      ItemStyle-cssclass="logtd" 
      ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
```